# JPA: Errors in named query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, named-query

I get the exception `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: ElaborazionePagamentiMaggioriOneri.estrai` but the named query looks correct to me. I also get

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: ElaborazionePagamentiMaggioriOneri is not mapped [FROM ElaborazionePagamentiMaggioriOneri e  WHERE e.dataInizioLancio IS NULL AND e.dataFineLancio IS NULL AND e.distinta IS NULL]
```

My entity is the following:

```
@Entity(name="ELABORAZIONE_PAGAMENTI")
@Table(name="ELABORAZIONE_PAGAMENTI")
@NamedQuery(name="ElaborazionePagamentiMaggioriOneri.estrai", 
query="FROM ElaborazionePagamentiMaggioriOneri e  WHERE e.dataInizioLancio IS NULL AND e.dataFineLancio IS NULL AND e.distinta IS NULL")
public class ElaborazionePagamentiMaggioriOneri {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID_ELABORAZIONE")
    private long idElaborazione;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_INTERVALLO")
    private Intervallo intervallo;

    @Column(name="IMPORTO_MINIMO")
    private BigDecimal importoMinimo;

    @Column(name="IMPORTO_MASSIMO")
    private BigDecimal importoMassimo;

    @Column(name="LIMITE_DISPOSIZIONI")
    private Long limiteDisposizioni;

    @Column(name="DATA_INIZIO_LANCIO")
    private Calendar dataInizioLancio;

    @Column(name="DATA_FINE_LANCIO")
    private Calendar dataFineLancio;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_DISTINTA")
    private DistintaMaggioriOneri distinta;
```

What is the origin of the error? I have double checked the JPQL syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Entity name` used with `@Entity` and the name of the entity you are using inside Select query  should be same, if you are not using entity name with `@Entity` then class name should be used with the Select query. Check this properly.

Comment: Unbelievable it works like a charm. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that if you put the annotation `@Entity(name="ELABORAZIONE_PAGAMENTI")` you set the name of the entity to be ELABORAZIONE_PAGAMENTI.
There are two solutions:

- modify the named query into `FROM ELABORAZIONE_PAGAMENTI e  WHERE e.dataInizioLancio IS NULL AND e.dataFineLancio IS NULL AND e.distinta IS NULL`
- modify the `@Entity` annotation by removing the `name` property

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `SELECT` in your query.

```
query="SELECT e FROM ElaborazionePagamentiMaggioriOneri e  WHERE
```

Comment: The missing `SELECT e` is valid Hibernate syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to missing SELECT, the "is not mapped" error is probably because you don't have the class registered in persistence.xml.